# JCheckBox components doesn't show on JPanel after re adding them

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jcheckbox

i am trying to make a JCheckBox list inside a JScrollPanel which is contained in a JDialogBox.Here is my code:

```
public void initTableChoices(DatabaseInit db){

    checkList = new ArrayList<>();

    //containerToScroll is the JPane, with boxLayout, that contains all the JCheckBoxes

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(containerToScroll); 
    scrollPane.setSize((this.getSize().width/2),this.getSize().height - 10);
    scrollPane.setLocation((ExportDialogBox.getSize().width)/2, 0);

    ExportDialogBox.setSize(defaultSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < db.numberOfTables; i++){

        checkList.add(new JCheckBox(db.fileNames[i], false));
        containerToScroll.add(checkList.get(i));

    }

    ExportDialogBox.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    containerToScroll.revalidate();
    containerToScroll.repaint();
    containerToScroll.updateUI();
    scPane.revalidate();
    scPane.repaint(); 
    ExportDialogBox.revalidate();
    ExportDialogBox.repaint();
}
```

The above method, when is called for the first time, does what i want and has the following outcome:

[The DialogBox after calling the method **InitTableChoices** for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0v4F.png)

When i want to delete all the JCheckBoxes to create a few new ones, and later call the initTableChoices method to paint them,i first call the below method to remove them:

```
    public void deleteTableChoices(DatabaseInit db){


    checkList.removeAll(checkList);
    containerToScroll.removeAll();

    scPane.revalidate();
    scPane.repaint();
    containerToScroll.revalidate();
    containerToScroll.repaint();
    ExportDialogBox.revalidate();
    ExportDialogBox.repaint();

}
```

and then call the **InitTableChoices** method again,and i have the following outcome:

[The DialogBox after calling the methods **DeleteTableChoices** and **InitTableChoices** after the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLmgy.png)

So it only shows the first JCheckBox i have on the list without showing the others.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `initTableChoices` method line

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(containerToScroll);
```

will add `containerToScroll` as a child of the `scrollPane` component.

When you run `initTableChoices` a second time, `containerToScroll` will be assigned to a **new** `JScrollPane` instance but this new `JScrollPane` instance is not added into the component hierarchy. As a result, you are effectively removing `containerToScroll` from your component hierarchy.

My suggestion would be to extract the loop that actually adds check boxes to `containerToScroll` into a new method, have `initTableChoices` call this method, and replace the second call of `initTableChoices` with a call to the new method.

Comment: My fault,in ExportDialogBox.add(scPane, BorderLayout.CENTER) i am using scrollPane instead of scPane.Just edited it in the question